# Can I use numpy array with dtype=object to share list of arbitrary type across class instances?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is what I want to achieve:

I have a class `MyData` that holds some sort of data.

Now in class `A` I store a sequence of data with attribute name `data_list` and type `List[MyData]`.

Suppose `MyData` instances are data with different type index. Class `A` is a management class. I need `A` to hold all the data to implement sampling uniformly from all data.

But some other operations that are type-specific also need to be done. So a base class `B` and derived class `B1,B2...` is designed to account for each type of data. An instance of class `A` have a list of `B` instances as member, each storing data points with one type. Code that illustrates this: `B.data_list = A.data_list[start_index:start_index+offset]`.

`A` have methods that returns some of the data, and `B` have methods that may modify some of the data.

Now here is the problem: I need to pass data by reference, so that any modification by member function of `B` is also visible from the side of `A`.

If I use python builtin List to store data, modifications by `B` won't be visible for `A`. I did some experiment using np.array(data_list, dtype=object), it seemed to work. But I'm not familiar with such kind of usage and not sure if it works for data of any type, and whether there will be performance concerns, etc.

Any suggestions or alternatives? Thanks!!

Illustrating code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, data_list, n_segment):
        self.data_list = data_list
        data_count = len(data_list)
        segment_length=data_count // n_segment
        self.segments = [self.data_list[segment_length*i:segment_length*(i+1)] for i in range(n_segment)]
        self.Bs = [B(segment) for segment in self.segments]

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.data_list[item]

class B:
    def __init__(self, data_list):
        self.data_list = data_list

    def modify(self, index, data):
        self.data_list[index]=data

A_data_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
A_instance = A(A_data_list, n_segment=3)
print(A_instance[0]) # get 1
A_instance.Bs[0].modify(0,2) # modify A[0] to be 2
print(A_instance[0]) # still get 1
```

Note that in the above example changing A_data_list to numpy array will solve my problem, but in my case elements in list are objects which cannot be stacked into numpy arrays.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can put objects in a `numpy` array, but it's often a case of "can I put a chicken in my filing cabinet?" - technically yes, but it's not nearly as useful  as one might think.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class `A`, the `segments` are all copies of portions of `data_list`. Thus, so are `Bs` items. When you try to modify values, `A.Bs` are modified, but not the corresponding elements in `A.data_list`.

With numpy, it is probable that you have memory views instead. So when a value is modified, it affects both `A.Bs` and `A.data_list`. It is still bad form though.

Here is how to fix your classes so that the proper values are modified:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, data_list, n_segment):
        self.data_list = data_list
        data_count = len(data_list)
        segment_length = data_count // n_segment
        r = range(0, (n_segment + 1) * segment_length, segment_length)
        slices = [slice(i, j) for i, j in zip(r, r[1:])]
        self.Bs = [B(self.data_list, slice_) for slice_ in slices]

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.data_list[item]

class B:
    def __init__(self, data_list, slice_):
        self.data_list = data_list
        self.data_slice = slice_

    def modify(self, index, data):
        a_ix = list(range(*self.data_slice.indices(len(self.data_list))))[index]
        self.data_list[a_ix] = data
```

Test:

```
A_data_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
a = A(A_data_list, n_segment=3)

>>> a[0]
1

a.Bs[0].modify(0, 2) # modify A[0] to be 2
>>> a[0]
2

a.Bs[1].modify(1, -5)
>>> vars(a)
{'data_list': [2, 2, 3, 4, -5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 ... }

a.Bs[2].modify(-1, -1)  # modify last element of segment #2
>>> vars(a)
{'data_list': [2, 2, 3, 4, -5, 6, 7, 8, -1],
 ... }

>>> A_instance.Bs[0].modify(3, 0)
IndexError: ... list index out of range
```

**Note**: This updated answer would also deal with arbitrary slices, including, hypothetically, ones with a `step` greater than 1.

Comment: I know why I'm getting what I'm getting in the above example, my problem is whether similar behavior for general object is possible.  Edit: the use of slice solves my problem, thanks!

Comment: Right. See my updated answer. I still think it is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) though, as this modification of `A`'s data via `B` class is quite sneaky. It's hard to know how to fix it without knowing what the larger goal is.

Comment: FYI: I just fixed a bug in my handling of `IndexError` conditions.

Comment: And now with better handling of slices, which allows things such as `a.Bs[i].modify(-1, value)` as well as arbitrary slices, including, hypothetically, ones with `step` greater than 1.

Comment: OP can keep having the classes A and B, their case looks like they just need to make a `__setitem__` for A